# Repeat a sequence of operations in R changing one variable

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

i'm manipulating a dataframe in R. I need do perform these operations:

```
is.na(rivalry[x,RT])

z<-which(is.na(rivalry[x,RT]) == TRUE)[1] - 1

key_duration<-paste0("key_duration", z)

key_press<-paste0("KeyPress", z)

key_press<-paste0(key_press, "RT")

rivalry[x,key_duration]<- 15000 - rivalry[x,key_press]
```

I'm a beginner in R so there might be a better way to do what i need. This code check which element is NA, perform an operation and finally write the result in the appropriate space in the dataframe.
The code works well but i need to do this for every row that i have ("x" in this code). It could be possible to do these operations for every rows?
Thanks

Comment: possibly by omitting `x` altogether? R works nicely over entire columns if you do not specify the row number.

Comment: You never need an explicit comparison to `TRUE`, just `is.na(rivalry[x,RT])` will do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ira ! i think that isn't good for me because i need a single value in the second operation.
I think that the best way is to find a method for doing all operations with row 1 and then with row 2 and go on...

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks! but i need to identify the first position in the vector in which the value is TRUE

Comment: If you provide some sample of your data (using the `dput` function) and an example of desired output, we should be able to help you easily.

Comment: @ira It's very complicated!! 
I'll try to explain. I have a dataset in which each row is a stimulus (experimental psychology) and columns are the keys pressed in 15s of stimulus duration. The hard part is that i have to subtract columns from each other to obtain the absolute (not cumulative) time of the key pressed. So the duration of the last key pressed is 15s - the cumulative time until the last key. I know that for a specific row the last key pressed is the position before the first TRUE(given by the is.na). so i have to perform the 15-cumulative time of the last key in different position

Comment: When you compare a logical value to `TRUE` the logical value *already is* `TRUE/FALSE`. So you *never* have to explicitly compare `logical == TRUE`. This can only give either `TRUE == TRUE` or `FALSE == TRUE` and the result is still the logical value you started with.

Comment: What @ira is asking is whether you can post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(rivalry)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(rivalry, 20))`.